# button tag submitting

Tags: html, button

i am using this plain html code inside an aspx page. it renders well, but when clicked it submits / reloads the page. i dont want anything to be  done on click of this button. whats d issue

```
                            <button>
                                btn1</button>
                            <button>
                                btn2</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

It'll default to type=submit if no type is explicitly given.

You want to put

```
<button type="button">btn1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<button>`.  Use `<input>` instead:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" />
```

Also, worth noting (from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> If you use the button element in an
>   HTML form, different browsers will
>   submit different values. Internet
>   Explorer will submit the text between
>   the `<button>` and `</button>` tags, while
>   other browsers will submit the content
>   of the value attribute. Use the input
>   element to create buttons in an HTML
>   form.

Comment: There are many advantages to using button. If you don't rely on the button submit value (you rarely do), it's very handy

Comment: I try to avoid it.  There's nothing it does that I can't accomplish without it.  But that's just me.

Comment: Bootstrap promotes the user of buttons

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if by pure html you can do so however this way you can black the default submit behaviour:

`<button id="a" onclick="return false;">button</button>`